# Is this really fair?

Tags: support, account-suspension

I was looking at a question that I had answered, and the person who had asked the question had many badges (including a gold badge and 6 silver badges), but only 1 point. And when I click on the profile of that person, the profile says that it is suspended until **November of 2021** because of "voting irregularities." Here is a screenshot of the above profile:

[image]

These voting irregularities are (I assume) the person in question having a bunch of downvotes on questions/answers that others deem appropriate. This person has been an integral part of multiple communities, with 251 points in matter modeling and hundreds, if not thousands in ELL, which is where I found this profile. This has been happening more and more often, with dedicated users being suspended for things such as voting irregularities. So my question is as following: Is it fair for these committed users (across all sites) that obviously add to the community to be suspended for such a long period of time over something as inconclusive as "voting irregularities?" Because to me, it seems a little harsh to suspend a veteran account (which has contributed greatly) for such a long period of time, and I believe that this should be lessened or a warning should be issued beforehand. Any thoughts on this issue would be greatly appreciated as well as to where I can find what constitutes as voting irregularities, because it seems kind of broad and vague.

EDIT: I looked further at the profile of this person and found the following:

[image]

So I have absolutely no idea as to how 7 votes would lead to a suspension over voting irregularities.

Comment: "*These voting irregularities are (I assume) the person in question having a bunch of downvotes on questions/answers that others deem appropriate.*" it usually means actual voting fraud, not "voted against the majority".

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you for clarifying that, but I would like to ask the following: How can a user commit voting fraud in SE?

Comment: “These voting irregularities are (I assume) the person in question having a bunch of downvotes on questions/answers that others deem appropriate.” - Users are absolutely not suspended if they receive downvoted from other users.  Voting irregularities is a generic suspension reason that likely suggests the user was giving themselves upvotes to their own contributions and/or upvoting the same users.  Behavior like this is often described as a sock puppet.  However, chances of you being told the entire reason the user is suspended by a moderator, is less than zero.

Comment: For example, participating in a voting ring, using sockpuppet accounts to vote, or repeatedly vote for or against a particular user.

Comment: “How can a user commit voting fraud in SE?” - Issuing an upvote to their question an contribution using another profile and/or having another profile upvote their contributions that is routine (I.e a friend or family in the same house or company).  Voting fraud is taken seriously, the chances of this user not actually committing that fraud, is less likely than a moderator submitting proof of that fraud as an answer to this question.  Moderators don’t share details of about user’s suspension.

Comment: @Ramhound If that is not the account that is committing fraud, why would that account be suspended instead of the account that was actually committing fraud, or would they both be suspended?

Comment: As far as having only seven votes, one of two things happened: either there are more votes cast by a sock puppet of the user, or the user voted on things but those votes were later invalidated by staff or by the serial voting detection script.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because questions on this site, Meta Stack Exchange, [are expected to relate to the entire SE network as a whole, not just one specific site](/q/355783/377214). Also, moderators are under policy to not publicly disclose the reasons of a user's suspension without the consent of the user themselves, so you won't receive any useful info out of this post unless the user later brings it up themselves.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog Ok thanks. You can close the question. I know it is kind of off topic, but I honestly didn't know what i should do with what I found because at the time it seemed a little bit sus.

Comment: @JoeKerr - I am suggesting the profile that was suspended absolutely was committing fraud or was part of a group of users committing voting fraud.  I personally dislike it when users commit voting irregularities.  **The fact it’s only a year suspension is disappointing.** The user can dispute their suspension through the appropriate avenues.

Comment: @JoeKerr You could have asked it on ELL meta rather than MSE, if you're truly focused on the treatment of a single specific user - but, regardless, the answer below is all that a third party will get out of the situation - we don't publicly discuss a user's suspension history unless the user explicitly gives permission to mods or staff to do so.

Comment: Can you make the title more specific?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's not really much that we can talk about in public about a specific user but someone doesn't generally make it to a year long suspension without having done something repeatedly after several warnings. That's how we guide moderators - generally a warning followed by 7, 30, and finally 365-day suspensions for repeated infractions, particularly for the same or similar activities.

There are several ways that accounts can commit voting fraud, including by using fake accounts to vote for a primary account (sockpuppeting) or by using fake accounts to target votes at someone else. In these cases, the standard action is to delete the sock accounts and suspend the primary account with an explanation of how voting on our network works.

You can also commit voting fraud with a single account by targeting your votes at one other user - targeted voting is not allowed, particularly targeted downvoting, so someone who downvotes another user a lot may be suspended for the abusive behavior of attacking a person with downvotes. If this is discovered, the votes are invalidated by staff (mods can't do this) and the user will often be suspended with information about how votes should be cast based on the content of the post, not who wrote it.

I can understand that you find this troubling but, should it not be more troubling to think that someone achieved that high-rep status by falsely inflating their own reputation or chose to use their voting privileges to target another user on the site for votes? That is something that I don't like, whether it's done for a positive (upvotes) or negative (downvotes) reason.

Someone who has fallen into this several times, so that they have made their way to a full year suspension, may be struggling to understand what I see as a very simple request - vote on content, not the people creating it. How much reputation a user has amassed in the time they've spent on the site shouldn't really impact that much - and 1k reputation - which may seem like a lot to some, isn't actually that much in the grand scheme of some sites.

Answer (score 10):

> Is it fair for these committed users (across all sites) that obviously add to the community to be suspended for such a long period of time over something as inconclusive as "voting irregularities?"

Objectively, **yes**.

You don't know any further details other than the fact that they were suspended for voting irregularities, and year-long bans are **not** given lightly.

We mortals only see this from one perspective - maybe two if the person who was suspended posts about their experience on social media (and [that has happened before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288229/1079354)).  You're not going to get the full picture, so establishing if it's "fair" is above our pay grade by a ***lot***.

Comment: Ironic that you made a decision which you yourself say, in your words, is above your pay grade.

Comment: @user1271772: Where'd I make a decision?  Not seein' it.